# read user input of double type

Tags: c#, parsing, loops, console

I have found this answered in other places using loops, but I wasn't sure if there is actually a function that I'm not finding that makes this easier, or if this is a possible (in my opinion) negative side to C#.

I'm trying to read in a double from user input like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input your total salary: ") // i input 100
double totalSalary = Console.Read(); //reads in the 1, changes to 49.
```

I've found a couple other posts on this, and they all have different answers, and the questions asked aren't exactly the same either.  If i just want the user input read in, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: you get a 49 because that is the ascii code for '1', Console.Read reads only one character at a time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to check the entire thing on it's way in.. as `Console.Read()` returns an integer.

```
double totalSalary;
if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalSalary)) {
    // .. error with input
}
// .. totalSalary is okay here.
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
double Salary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplest answer to your question:

```
double insert_name = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
double d;
if (!Double.TryParse(input, out d))
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
double r = d * Math.Pi;
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, can you explain, or anyone else for that matter, why it's necessary to have the double r = d*Math.Pi?  Unless I'm not understanding what Math.Pi is, it seems like an odd thing to do.  Thanks.

Comment: This returns invalid output for me.. Input: 12.5, Output: 39.2699081698724. It would appear that the `Math.PI` multiplication breaks it.. ?