# How to convert Console.ReadLine() to double in simple calculator ? C# Problem with exception

Tags: c#, exception, type-conversion

I used `double.Parse` and `Convert.ToDouble` and got the same error

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

When I write in console `10.2` or any other double number.

I learnt from a tutorial and I followed it step by step but I have no idea how to solve this.

Also I am using Visual Studio.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
double num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter operator: ");
string op = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
double num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (op == "+")
{
    Console.Write(num1 + num2);
}
else if (op == "-")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
}
else if (op == "/")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
}
else if (op == "*")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
}
```

Comment: Always use the `TryParse` variants when parsing user input, additionally with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or the culture, if you have a culture issue

Comment: Are you in a place where they write 10.2 as 10,2?

Comment: I've compiled and tested this code and it works as intended. You are simply inputting wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read user input of double type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813166/read-user-input-of-double-type)

Comment: Nope, my imput was "10.2". in first enter.

Comment: Double.TryParse, double.Parse, Convert.ToDouble - everything throwing the same ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be your culutral setting.
Some countries uses a `.` others uses a `,`

try:

```
double num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or set the separator like:

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
double num2 = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), culture);
```

Comment: Truth. I have never used "," in any language only "." Ehh ... I tried with "," and it works normally. God, how much time wasted :(( feels bad haha, thank you for your time and total senseless post...damn... -.-

Comment: Bonus ask: Is there a lot of difference caused by this?

Comment: Best you look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8 if you want to know more

Comment: Also worth mentioning the Turkish "i", where calling ToUpper() doesn't return "I" - and ToLower() on "I" doesn't return "i". See, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3550213/1364007

Answer (score 0):

missing Line in WriteLine in lines 4 and 11

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
double num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter operator: ");
string op = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
double num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (op == "+")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
}
else if (op == "-")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
}
else if (op == "/")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
}
else if (op == "*")
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
}
```

this is fixed version as op has the broken version posted