# CS0029 when reading user input

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a calculator and I have the error CS0029.
here is the code:

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator\n");

            Rechnungplus();
        }

        static void Rechnungplus()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("after typing a/(every) number press enter.");
            double a = Console.ReadLine();
            double b = Console.ReadLine();
            double c = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine($"\n{a} + {b} = {c}");
        }
    }
}
```

I searched for a solution and I found a question from someone with a similar problem. Someone said he/she should try:

```
double a = (Console.ReadLine());
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: TryParse method is a really good way how to ensure that there's really a number in a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read user input of double type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813166/read-user-input-of-double-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.Readline()` returns a string. If you want a `double`, you'll have to parse it. E.g.:

```
double a = Double.Parse(Console.Readline());
double b = Double.Parse(Console.Readline());
```

Answer (score 7):

[`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1) returns a `string`, not a double , so you need
to convert it to one. One of the options would be:

```
double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

But this will throw an excepion, if string can't be parsed. More safer approach would be using [`Double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) though, which returns a boolean marking if conversion was successful. For example:

```
double a;
while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number:");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Console.ReadLine` returns a `string`. It can't be directly converted to a `double`. You should use `double.Parse()`, which can parse a `string` to a `double`. An example:

```cs
double d = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Be aware that `double.Parse` will [throw an exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/) if you pass it an invalid value. A safer alternative is [`double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 1):

Console.Readline() method returns string. You must cast it to a double before you can start your program.

Do this:

```
double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
double b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
```

Or better.

```
static void Rechnungplus()
{
    string temp;
    bool isValid;
    double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("after typing a/(every) number press enter.");

    isValid = false;
    while (!isValid)
    {
        temp = Console.ReadLine();
        if(double.TryParse(temp,out a))
        {
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Only (decimal) numbers are allowed.");
        }
    }

    isValid = false;
    while (!isValid)
    {
        temp = Console.ReadLine();
        if (double.TryParse(temp, out b))
        {
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Only (decimal) numbers are allowed.");
        }
    }

    c = a + b;

    Console.WriteLine($"\n{a} + {b} = {c}");
}
```